# UIScrollview contents not scrolling and sticky

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

i created a new UIScrollView using the interface builder, i put a label with a long text, the scrollbar is showing and sliding although the contents became sticky and not hiding while scrolling

screenshots
[[1](https://thumbs.rapidshare.com/thumbs/600/61D/B3641E8EAE1BA97C4F5AB67CA2065.jpg)] [[2](https://thumbs.rapidshare.com/thumbs/600/D1E/0E8B0DEA90DD5F4B23A918624F9AF.jpg)]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    title.text = @"hellllllo world hellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo worldhellllllo world";

    scrollview.contentSize =
    CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+600);
    //scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    //scrollview.minimumZoomScale = 0.75;
    scrollview.clipsToBounds = YES;
    //  scrollview.bounces = YES;
    scrollview.superview.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
    //scrollview.delegate = self;

    [scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

Comment: What actually you want to do ?

Comment: The contents isn't scrolling while you move the scroll up and down, this is considered as a bug!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the "title" label is a subview of the scroll-view.

It appears to me that it is misplaced to be at the same level as the scroll-view instead of below it.

[image: How it should look]

In your screenshot, a second problem is shown: the text is not displayed correctly. Make sure to wire the label to the "textLabel" property using Interface Builder.

Comment: the label is a sub view of scroll view , i missed to wire the outlet

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the scrollview size is less than the contentSize

Comment: i'm sure about that, the contentSize is bigger than scrollview with 600 pixel

Answer (score 0):

This was because of using xcode 4.5 for ios 6 , it adda constraints for each UIView subclass and causing that problem, solved by creating the view from earlier version for XCode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tick "Bounce Vertically" from Attribute Inspector for scrollView in interface builder.